# Return to libc- Buffer overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, libc

I am learning Buffer overflow attacks and I came across the following commands:
"ps aux|grep exploitme" using the process id obtained here, lets say it is 312
"gdb exploitme 312" is run and it magically mapped libc into the process. Usually why does the libc not get mapped into the process?If an attacker wants to overcome the 'nx' protection would he always rely on mapping the libc into the vulnerable program?Please explain.

**Return to libc- Buffer overflow**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lets say it is 312 "gdb exploitme 312" is run and it magically mapped libc into the process

You are confused: no mapping is actually happening during GDB attach; `libc.so.6` has *already* been mapped into the process long time ago.

All GDB is telling you with `Reading symbols from ... Loaded symbols from ...` is the GDB itself realized that `libc.so.6` is already mapped, and it (GDB) reads symbol table from `libc.so.6` so it can print address `0xb7f3bcde` in symbolized form as `__read_nocancel`.

You can confirm that `libc.so.6` is *already there* before you attach GDB with `cat /proc/312/maps`.

You can also stop GDB from automatically loading symbols for shared libraries (`set auto-solib-add off`) and observe that `Loaded symbols for...` disappear and that you get addresses instead of symbol names from GDB.

Comment: Thanks. It helps :)